# Can Qt synchronisation primitives be used with non-QThread threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread, qtcore

I want to use, say, `QSemaphore` with boost threads or c++ 11 threads. Is that allowed?

Comment: Curious, what is the value in using Qt's builtin primitives here? Why not use something for widely used like boost interprocess semaphore (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/interprocess/synchronization_mechanisms.html#interprocess.synchronization_mechanisms.semaphores) ?

Comment: @yankee2905: I'm not actually going to use boost, but fair point. Ofc if my threading library of choice has semaphore implementation I will use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm working on [pqConsole](https://github.com/CapelliC/pqConsole), where multithreading plays an important role.

Running a console for SWI-Prolog ([multithreaded](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=threads), implemented in C), the Qt GUI manages IO on behalf of user programs, executing in a background QThread, where the foreign language interface is instanced.

Threads can also be initiated from C side, and they get a dedicated console (see [interactor](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=interactor/0)/0), where the IO again is rendered on Qt GUI.

I'm using QMutex and QMutexLocker to syncronize (i.e. the simpler constructs), and AFAIK those are performing as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, yes, you can.

Note, you could also just use the boost semaphore available with that scenario. Also, QSemaphore currently does not use the pthread interface underneath, but some custom solution. There were discussions to refactor that later for utilizing the pthread features more.

Comment: I'd like to add a prooflink. `QSemaphore` is marked as thread-safe in the docs. [This page](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/threads-reentrancy.html) describes what thread safety means in Qt docs. And there is no requirements for using `QThread` on that page. So yes, it should work fine.